# Can I use ffmpeg to resize the timeline of a video file?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, resize, timeline, editing

I need to stretch the video to fit a specific time.

Is it possible with ffmpeg or do you guys know any other tool that could do the the work?

Answer (score 0):

Slowing down video:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter:v "setpts=2.0*PTS" output.mkv
```

Speeding up video:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -r 16 -filter:v "setpts=0.25*PTS" output.mkv
```

Speeding up audio:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter:a "atempo=2.0" -vn output.mkv
```

[Here is the full tutorial](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video)

Comment: thanks for answering! but in this way is gonna be hard to accomplish the exact duration!

Comment: @MrNobody See *Fit video into specific time* example in [Expand (extend) a video to an specific duration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14782280/).